# Android Dev : NO EC/IO?

Tags: java, android

Wondering how to get the `EC/IO` value on the Android Nexus One phone.

Actual methods given by Android class `android.telephony.SignalStrength` are:

```
/* Get the CDMA Ec/Io value in dB*10  */
int  getCdmaEcio() 

/* Get the EVDO Ec/Io value in dB*10  */
int  getEvdoEcio()
```

The problem is: I am on an UMTS / WCDMA Network, so, there is no way for me to actual get the value.

Any updates from Android? Or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

cdma is diffrent from wcdma/umts.
suggest to use GSM or HSUPA .

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8f8ac6a1f07da259?pli=1)?

> I never try this by myself but someone
>   told me that in Android world,  GSM
>   might actually mean UMTS. For example,
>   you use "CDMA" stack for  Verizon
>   phone and  "GSM" stack for ATT phone.

Comment: GSM does actually mean UMTS, as well as W-CDMA and all other standards that uses SIM card

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the point here, but what method should I use then. There is no getGSMEcio(), only Evdo and CDMA...

Thanks